# Is the set $\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}$ a partially ordered set with respect to the $⊆$ relation?

Tags: order-theory

The definition of partial order is:

Let $R$ be a relation on a set $S$. $R$ is a partial order if and only if the following three statements are true for every $a$, $b$, and $c$ in $S$:
Reflexive Property: $aRa$
Transitive Property: If $aRb$ and $bRc$, then $aRc$.
 Antisymmetric Property: If $aRb$ and $bRa$, then $a=b$

I think $\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}$ is a partial order because, the reflexive property is satisfied, since $a⊆a$ for any set $a$ in $\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}$, the transitive and antisymmetric properties are satisfied because the antecedent of the implication is false. Is this correct?

Comment: Not only that, **any** set of sets is partially ordered by that relation.

Comment: @bof yeah for the same reason, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the set $\{\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}\}$ is partially ordered by $\subseteq$ and your answer is essentially correct.

By the way, note that is not exact that the antecedent in the transitivity and symmetric conditions is always false, because $\{1\} \subseteq \{1\}$ and $\{2\} \subseteq \{2\}$ and $\{3\} \subseteq \{3\}$. But yes, you can say that transitivity and symmetry are satisfied in a trivial way.

Comment: Oh thank you! yeah that's what I meant, the other answer got me confused for a second, but that relation is defined because, the cartesian product of $S=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}$ has, for example, $(\{1\}, \{1\})$ as an element, so it is a subset of the $S⨯S$ and therefore it's a relation right?

Comment: @cekami7844 - Right!